# gcc unable to find "windows.h, winsock2.h and ws2tcpip.h" header files even after installing mingw package on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to create a c/c++ program using winsock2.h, windows.h and ws2tcpip.h in Linux. But I get the following error messages:

> cannot open source file "winsock2.h"C/C++(1696)

Likewise for windows.h

> cannot open source file "windows.h"C/C++(1696)

I have already installed Mingw on my system using this command

```
mingw-w64-common mingw-w64-i686-dev mingw-w64-tools mingw-w64-x86-64-dev
```

My Program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") 

 int main() { return 0; }
```

**VSC ver - 1.45.1**

**OS - Debian**

Comment: @qrdl but mingw package provides that windows specific development and runtime enviornment for linux.

Comment: @ShubhamMishra Did you feel deprived of using Linux socket API :( ?

Comment: @MohithReddy I am trying to creating an application which runs on window server

Comment: @qrdl can you please elaborate

Comment: This might be helpful: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/configure-intellisense-crosscompilation

Comment: @DavidMacek I have done changed same as this but I don't know where I am missing

Comment: You're not supposed to change your configuration to be exactly the same. You're supposed to configure VSCode to use the mingw-w64 toolchain (hint: `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`).

Answer (score 3):

The problems seem to be something related to "not finding header files". If with gcc to include the custom headers path (or directory), you do something as below.

**NOTE: My intentions here are not using the mingw offered headers with gcc; this is just for demonstration purpose.**

`dpkg -L mingw-w64-common` gives such output on my system.

```
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock2.h
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/ws2tcpip.h
```

`gcc -v test.c` gives such output on my system

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

So it is evident that the headers or not in the default search path. In this particular case, you need to compile with `gcc -I/usr/share/mingw-w64/include`. You give a similar option for your toolchain's compiler. But then you may need to deal with the linking errors based on what libraries your code is using.

Comment: As already mentioned elsewhere, to actually target Windows, you need to use the right toolchain, e.g. x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, not just the includes.

Comment: @DavidMacek Yes, it looks like that, and from the OP's error messages, we can conclude that he is using the mingw offered ``gcc`` instead of Linux's. But even in that case, the issue seems to be something related to not finding the header files. To the best of my knowledge even with the tool chain's compiler, we include the header directory with the option ``-I``, and I am going to edit my post to project in that direction, Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can conclude that. And I would think twice (or more) before implying that Debian's mingw-w64 GCC is not configured correctly.

Comment: @DavidMacek In that case, OP needs to provide information about his environment setup. And from your comment on his post, OP is using Linux and there is no Visual Studio IDE for Linux (unless it runs on wine, I did not try), so most probably he is using Visual Studio Code, and OP mentioned that in the bottom of the question. Now my real question is, Does VSC have some plugins to integrate the compilation process?

Comment: @Mohith thanks for help but I got same error message, I think this all set by default through C/C++ Configurations in VS

Answer (score 1):

The message format `cannot open source file "winsock2.h"C/C++(1696)` doesn't look like to me like something GCC would say.
Is it possible that while you installed MinGW-w64 you are not using its GCC compiler?
For MinGW-w64 to work you need to actualy us it's toolchain (compiler, linker).

Comment: Yes ``gcc`` reports the "header not found" in a different way. But the link [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/devel/mingw-w64-common) says the programs are compiled with gcc.

Comment: Did you compile with the mingw-w64 compiler on (Debian) Linux and then try to run it?
It makes perfect sense that wouldn't work as you're basically cross compiling for another operating system (Windows).

If you really want to run Windows executables on Linux maybe you should check out Wine.

Comment: I think the description meant GCC in general, not specifically `/usr/bin/gcc`. Did you try this? https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64

Comment: The error message is probably from VSCode (and maybe not even from a build).

Comment: @BrechtSanders I am using /usr/bin/gcc as a Compiler path and gcc-x64 as IntelliSense mode but I stuck on the same problem

Comment: @DavidMacek No I didn't try this one lets me check :)

Comment: @DavidMacek /usr/bin/gcc is the compiler for your operating system, it should be something like /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 if you want to compile for Windows 64-bit

If you compiling for Windows is not what you want than include files windows.h, winsock2.h, ws2tcpip.h make no sense. On Linux you need to look at sys/socket.h and other related headers.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "GCC in general, not specifically `/usr/bin/gcc`" and linked the mingw-w64 GCC. I'm also trying to guide our OP in question comments.